# Accessing Cloudant Couch with JSONP

Tags: jsonp, cloudant

I am trying to get a setup so that I can access Cloudant Couch directly without using a middle tier such as PHP, .NET, or Ruby.

It is possible to avoid the cross-domain problem with script injection or JSONP.  One can specify a

But this means that your only method can be a GET.

Does Cloudant have a URL convention or proxy that allows you to specify other methods with a GET?

For example you could DELETE a document with something like:

Thanks in advance.  Hoping for responses that are directly applicable, not the "why would you want to do that" kind of response.

Comment: My question is missing some text:  "One can specify a script such as "\<script src='any-domain-here' />" without encountering the cross-domain problem.

Comment: Oh, it looks like I didn't read your question correctly.  They have JSONP turned on but you want to know if there are other ways of contacting the service?  As I understand it, you should be able to POST and everything without needing JSONP ....

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a [virtual host](https://cloudant.com/blog/pretty-urls-with-cloudant/) on cloudant.  I don't think this will help you get around XSS same-origin policy though unless you run your entire application from this virtual host.

Comment: This doesn't solve my particular problem, but it's a very useful answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, they support CORS but not the wildcard syntax.  However, that should take care of most of your work.  I've posted to their support channels if they support returning JSONP but that does bring us to another work-around: try embeding self executing functions into the data object.  I'm betting that the CouchDB folks will prevent it from saving (as we don't want self-executing functions messing with CouchDB's innards) but it's worth a shot.

Comment: The purpose of JSONP is to be able to get a handle to your JSON, since there is no way to find an anonymous object, right?  Wrong!  There is a way to find an anonymous object and Google uses it in some of their apps. What they do is getElementByTagName("SCRIPT") and grab the last script tag loaded, and eval the text of the script.  Sounds funky but if it's good enough for Google, I can buy it.